# Power BI: Simple addition give wrong result

Tags: sum, powerbi, calculated-columns

I'm counting number of unique IDs per month in given timeframe and I've ancountered two strange things:
 1. Looking for the same thing but using two different approaches (value for each month and cumulative value month by month) gives different values. See screenshot below.
 2. When You'll add by hand values in first column (monthly value) the result is 868, when PowerBI summerize it - it's 864 o_O

any ideas?

[image: Formula for first column and result]

DAX Formulas below:

```
Y-1 Kandydaci = CALCULATE(
    distinctcount(getDataForTeb[ID_DANE_OSOBOWE]);
    DATESBETWEEN(
        getDataForTeb[Złożenie podania];
        DATE(YEAR(now())-1;4;1);
        IF(DATE(YEAR(NOW())-1;MONTH(NOW());DAY(NOW()))<=DATE(YEAR(NOW())-1;11;30);
            DATE(YEAR(NOW())-1;MONTH(NOW());DAY(NOW()));DATE(YEAR(NOW())-1;11;30)));
            ISBLANK(getDataForTeb[REZYGNACJA_DATA]))

Y-1 Kandydaci cumulative = CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(getDataForTeb[ID_DANE_OSOBOWE]);
    FILTER(
        ALL (getDataForTeb);
        AND (
            getDataForTeb[Złożenie podania] <= MAX(getDataForTeb[Złożenie podania])-364;
            AND (
                getDataForTeb[Złożenie podania] <= DATE(YEAR(NOW())-1; 11; 30);
                getDataForTeb[Złożenie podania] >= DATE(YEAR(NOW())-1; 4; 1)
            )
        )
    );
    ISBLANK(getDataForTeb[REZYGNACJA_DATA])
)
```

Another interesting example just from a while ago: different file, no DAX involved:

[image: Addition went crazy]

Comment: Isn't `DATE(YEAR(NOW())-1;MONTH(NOW());DAY(NOW()))<=DATE(YEAR(NOW())-1;11;30)` the same as `NOW() <= DATE(YEAR(NOW());11;30)`? I'm getting confused trying to see what your measure is really doing.

Comment: My command relate to the year before now.

Comment: Yes, but if 1 year before now is before 30 November 1 year ago, then it is also true that now is before 30 November this year.

Comment: But i need data from given period one year back to compare with same period this year

Comment: I mean the first part of the IF(), not the second or third arguments.

Comment: IF same day year ago was before 30th of November, 
then set it to same day one year ago, 
else set it to 30th of November one year ago.

It's about lasy day of measurment for comparison.

Comment: @Uzzy - Can you provide any sample data so that I can test a few ideas out on representative data?

Comment: It would be difficult - there are few several tables with relations and a lot of columns in each table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! This is the magic of `DISTINCTCOUNT()`. It has counted the number of distinct values for the `[ID_DANE_OSOBOWE]` column in each month, but when the measure is evaluated for all months, it does not double count the values which appear in more than one month.

Simplified:

```
| ID | Month |
+----+-------+
| 1  | March |
| 1  | April |
```

When you have a measure `My Measure = DISTINCTCOUNT(tbl[ID])` for each month the value will be 1, but when you do a distinct count for all months then the value will still be 1 because there is only one distinct value.

Comment: I've checked the data in excel, filtered out the same period on [Złożenie deklaracji] and counted the IDs that appeared more then once with different dates (in different months) and there are 7 of them. Other interesting thing is that colleague in my office is working on different report with different data source and is using the CALCULATE(SUM(... to count some things and in his case also Grand Total is not correct :/

Comment: Do some of the IDs occur more than one time in the same month?

Comment: No, but it might some time in the future. At this moment no.

Answer (score 0):

In general when you're getting strange results when grand total (calculated automatically) is different then sum of partial results it is either the case explained by mendosi above (regarding DISTINCTCOUNT) because of switching filter context for each row of calculation, or because some calculations count BLANK values as 1 - in March 2019 update of PowerBI a new DAX function was introduced: **DistinctCountNoBlank** which eliminates counting BLANK values.